# VB.NET Events not Firing

Tags: vb.net

I've received a project from another developer. Long story short, the program pulls several thousand entries from an SQL Database hosted on our internal network. The program displays the entries and allows you to filter them for convenience.

Recently we had an issue in which a table in our SQL Database was cleared (It's normally regenerated each day, but for several days it was blank.) Found the issue and solved it (Made no changes to the VB project) to repopulate the table; but since that point the VB project would no longer fire events.

The program is several thousand lines of code long, so I can not post the entire thing; but I will try my best to give symptoms:

1. The form object **can** fire events (Form_Closing, Form_Closed, etc.)
2. The existing controls (Radio button, buttons, picturebox, data grid view, etc) will not fire any events.
3. If I add a new control (such as a button), it will not fire events.
4. If a put a debug breakpoint at the sub that should be fired, it will not break.

Here's an example of a method that should be fired but is not fired:

```
`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("GOT IT!")
End Sub`
```

Here's the Form_Load sub:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeComponent()
    Try
        DataGridView_Items.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
        DataGridView_Items.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
        CheckBox_Highlight.DataBindings.Add("Visible", RadioButton_BD, "Checked")
        Try
            'Populates the DGV
            LoadTable()
            TableLayoutPanel_BD_Parts.Visible = True
            TableLayoutPanel_PF_Parts.Visible = False

            'Exits if no data was pulled from the database
            If dbDataSet.Rows.Count = 0 Or pfDataSet.Rows.Count = 0 Then Application.ExitThread()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(logFile)
                Log("Function Form1_Load says " & ex.Message & " @ " & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss"), w)
            End Using
        End Try

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        formLoaded = True
    Catch exx As Exception
        MsgBox(exx.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```

There is a backgroundworker, but it appears to work correctly and exit out.

All the forms can be interacted with; but do not fire events. (I can change the selection of the radio button, click the button, type into text boxes, etc.)

I know this is a little vague, I'm just hoping someone can give suggestions as to things that could cause this that I can look into. I can provide specifics; but I can't copy the entire code here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for information I could add to make it possible?

I've never seen this before, and it's possible that someone knows different things that would cause events not to fire; which they could share and could solve my problem. That was my hopes.

Comment: Have you tried running it on different machines (i.e., perhaps .NET Framework is somehow messed on a machine up and causing this)?  Do you have a backup of an older version that you can test to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah, I've run it on 3 machines. What's weird is that the binary that was working prior to the SQL database having issues exhibits the exact same problem. I've verified that it is pulling entries from the database successfully by monitoring the dataset and manually entering the stored procedure.

Comment: I found a strange thing: why you `InitializeComponent()` in `Form_Load()` instead of constructor?

Comment: @tezzo Yes you are right. the InitializeComponent() should be in the constructor.

Comment: Haha, wow.  Thanks guys. I thought about it for a moment. Then I created another form to see where it would put the InitializeComponent call; and it didn't create one. So I created a new project just to verify that there would be no InitializeComponent call and there wasn't. Commenting out InitializeComponent solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very strange thing in your code is that you call `InitializeComponent()` from `Form_Load`.
Usually this method is called in `Form` constructor so you can remove it from `Form_Load`.

I made some test on my PC: if you called twice `InitializeComponent()` you duplicate every controls in the form and their events doesn't fire anymore maybe because you have two controls with the same name.